# Passing numpy integer array to c code

Tags: numpy, cython, python-extensions

I'm trying to write Cython code to dump a dense feature matrix, target vector pair to libsvm format faster than sklearn's built in code. I get a compilation error complaining about a type issue with passing the target vector (a numpy array of ints) to the relevant c function.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "cdump.h":
    int filedump( double features[], int numexemplars, int numfeats, int target[], char* outfname)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def fastdumpdense_libsvmformat(np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=2] X, y, outfname):
    if X.shape[0] != len(y):
        raise ValueError("X and y need to have the same number of points")

    cdef int numexemplars = X.shape[0]
    cdef int numfeats = X.shape[1]

    cdef bytes py_bytes = outfname.encode()
    cdef char* outfnamestr = py_bytes

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2, mode="c"] X_c
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] y_c
    X_c = np.ascontiguousarray(X, dtype=np.double)
    y_c = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=np.int)
    retval = filedump( &X_c[0,0], numexemplars, numfeats, &y_c[0], outfnamestr)

    return retval
```

When I attempt to compile this code using distutils, I get the error

```
cythoning fastdump_svm.pyx to fastdump_svm.cpp

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------ ...

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2, mode="c"] X_c
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1, mode="c"] y_c
    X_c = np.ascontiguousarray(X, dtype=np.double)
    y_c = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=np.int)
    retval = filedump( &X_c[0,0], numexemplars, numfeats, &y_c[0], outfnamestr)
                                                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

fastdump_svm.pyx:24:58: Cannot assign type 'int_t *' to 'int *'
```

Any idea how to fix this error? I originally was following the paradigm of passing  y_c.data, which works, but this is apparently not the recommended way.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `dtype=np.dtype("i")` when initiating a numpy array to match the C `int` on your machine.

```
cdef int [:] y_c
c_array = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=np.dtype("i"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `numpy.int_t` is not the same as `int`, you can easily check this by having your program print `sizeof(numpy.int_t)` and `sizeof(int)`.

`int` is a c int, defined by the c standard as being at least 16 bits, but it's 32 bits on my machine. `numpy.int_t` is usually 32 bits or 64 bits depending on whether you're using a 32 or 64 bit version of numpy, but of course there is some exception (probably for windows users). If you want to know which numpy dtype matches your c_int you can do `np.dtype(cytpes.c_int)`.

So to pass your numpy array to c code you can do:

```
import ctypes
cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim=1, mode="c"] y_c
y_c = np.ascontiguousarray(y, dtype=ctypes.c_int)
retval = filedump( &X_c[0,0], numexemplars, numfeats, &y_c[0], outfnamestr)
```

Comment: The dtype in the cdef should be int_t, no? When I try it without int_t I get an error about not being able to cast pointers to Python objects. When I use int_t, I get the same error as before about casting from int_t * to int *.

Comment: Sorry about my last comment, I seem to have misunderstood your followup question. The cdef should have the same type as the function declaration of `filedump` so if the argument is defined as `int target[]`, the cdef should use `int`. If you can change the signature of `filedump` you can set them both to `np.int_t` for example, but they should be the same. Make sure you're using `int` and not `np.int`, the first is a c basic type (at least when you use it in a cdef block) and the latter is a python type.