# What does `mode='c'` do in numpy.ndarray[..., mode='c'] do?

Tags: python, cython, numpy-ndarray

I am modifying [cython code](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/develop/src/sage/plot/complex_plot.pyx) that makes plots of complex-valued functions. This code includes something equivalent to the following:

```py
cimport numpy as cnumpy

def do_something():
    # Buffer types only allowed as function local variables, so put
    # this inside a function.
    cdef cnumpy.ndarray[cnumpy.float_t, ndim=3, mode='c'] rgb
    pass
```

What does the `mode='c'` kwarg do? I don't see this as an option on [the numpy.ndarray documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html?highlight=mode) (or anywhere else in the numpy documentation), or mentioned in the [cython for numpy users](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) documentation/tutorial, or mentioned in cython's [working with numpy](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) documentation/tutorial.

I am not fluent in cython, but I do know python and C. I see from [other questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23435756/1141805) that this is not a rare argument, but I can't find documentation or explanation for what this does.

Comment: That question is from 2014. Maybe the API has changed since. The linked documentation does not mention kwarg, but it has "order": Row-major (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument `mode` maps to Python's [buffer protocol's flags](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html#shape-strides-suboffsets):

- `"c"` means `PyBUF_C_CONTIGUOUS`
- `"fortran"` means `PyBUF_F_CONTIGUOUS`
- `"strided"` means `PyBUF_STRIDES`

there is also `"full"` which maps to `PyBUF_INDIRECT` and thus doesn't make sense for numpy-arrays.

Knowing, that the memory layout/mode is "c" or "fortran" would lead to generation of a more performant code, but then only numpy arrays with this layout (flags of the array must be either `C_CONTIGUOUS=true` for `mode="c"` or `F_CONTIGUOUS=true` for `mode="fortran"`) would be accepted.

On the other hand `mode="strided"` would accept any numpy ndarray, but the generated C-code would be less performant.

---

The gory details:

To access the content of a numpy array Cython uses Python's buffer protocol. Whenever there is a `np.ndarray` in the Cython code, there will be a corresponding `__Pyx_Buffer` variable in the C-code, for generation of which the [class `BufferEntry`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/1894e0f7b3e69531edccded47226f169b871dee8/Cython/Compiler/Buffer.py#L196) is responsible.

To get the buffer from the array object, the C-function [`__Pyx_GetBufferAndValidate` will be emitted.](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/1894e0f7b3e69531edccded47226f169b871dee8/Cython/Compiler/Buffer.py#L349) The `mode`-argument will be translated into the buffer-protocol flags used by the above function [in `BufferEntry.get_flags`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/1894e0f7b3e69531edccded47226f169b871dee8/Cython/Compiler/Buffer.py#L267-L281):

```py
def get_flags(buffer_aux, buffer_type):
    flags = 'PyBUF_FORMAT'
    mode = buffer_type.mode
    if mode == 'full':
        flags += '| PyBUF_INDIRECT'
    elif mode == 'strided':
        flags += '| PyBUF_STRIDES'
    elif mode == 'c':
        flags += '| PyBUF_C_CONTIGUOUS'
    elif mode == 'fortran':
        flags += '| PyBUF_F_CONTIGUOUS'
    else:
        assert False
    if buffer_aux.writable_needed: flags += "| PyBUF_WRITABLE"
    return flags
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it's an equivalent to the `order` argument in the [numpy ndarray docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).